# Failed to import "android" module. Could not remove android presplash

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I am new in kivy. I made one app, and it working fine in pc. But when I run it in mobile it getting crush. I checked in using adb logcat I am getting this type of error. Can you help on this

> I/python  (25833): [WARNING] Call to deprecated function **init** in
>   /home/rup/workspace/TeachersApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/artoflivingteachersupport/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/listview.py
>   line 846.Called from
>   /home/rup/workspace/TeachersApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/artoflivingteachersupport/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py
>   line 564 by _apply_rule(). I/python  (25833): [WARNING] Call to
>   deprecated function **init** in
>   /home/rup/workspace/TeachersApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/artoflivingteachersupport/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/adapters/adapter.py
>   line 112.Called from
>   /home/rup/workspace/TeachersApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/artoflivingteachersupport/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/adapters/simplelistadapter.py
>   line 54 by **init**(). I/python  (25833): [WARNING] Call to deprecated
>   function **init** in
>   /home/rup/workspace/TeachersApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/artoflivingteachersupport/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/abstractview.py
>   line 43.Called from
>   /home/rup/workspace/TeachersApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/artoflivingteachersupport/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/listview.py
>   line 866 by **init**(). I/python  (25833): [WARNING] Call to
>   deprecated function **init** in
>   /home/rup/workspace/TeachersApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/artoflivingteachersupport/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/adapters/adapter.py
>   line 112.Called from
>   /home/rup/workspace/TeachersApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/artoflivingteachersupport/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/adapters/listadapter.py
>   line 185 by **init**(). I/python  (25833): [WARNING] [Base        ]
>   Unknown  provider I/python  (25833): [INFO   ] [Base        ]
>   Start application main loop I/python  (25833): [ERROR  ] [Base
>   ] Failed to import "android" module. Could not remove android
>   presplash. I/python  (25833): [WARNING] Call to deprecated function
>   **init** in /home/rup/workspace/TeachersApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/artoflivingteachersupport/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/selectableview.py
>   line 39.Called from
>   /home/rup/workspace/TeachersApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/artoflivingteachersupport/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/listview.py
>   line 594 by **init**(). I/python  (25833): [INFO   ] [Base        ]
>   Leaving application in progress... I/python  (25833): Python for
>   android ended. I/DEBUG   (26018):     #00 pc 000bf63a 
>   /data/app/org.aolsc.artoflivingteachersupport-2/lib/arm/libpython2.7.so
>   (PyThreadState_New+93) I/DEBUG   (26018):     #01 pc 000c9975 
>   /data/app/org.aolsc.artoflivingteachersupport-2/lib/arm/libpython2.7.so
>   (PyThread_acquire_lock+76)

Answer (score 1):

```
[Base] Failed to import "android" module. Could not remove android presplash.
I/python (25833): [WARNING] Call to deprecated function init in /home/rup/workspace/TeachersApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/artoflivingteachersupport/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/selectableview.py line 39.
 Called from /home/rup/workspace/TeachersApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/artoflivingteachersupport/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/listview.py line 594 by init().
I/python (25833): [INFO ] [Base ] Leaving application in progress... 
I/python (25833): Python for android ended.
```

I strongly believe the fault is somewhere else as the `android` module doesn't crash anything, only notifies a user that it couldn't remove presplash, because it wasn't available.

If the `android` module was responsible, there wouldn't be the next line about `ListView` and it'd just crash right there. Also, `ListView` is getting old and you should definitely replace it with [`RecycleView`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) as it's more reliable and improved.

Comment: I am trying to use RecycleView also but, I got "No module named recycleview" error. But it is in system

Comment: You'll need to use the master branch of Kivy, not the current stable version `1.9.1`.

Comment: if you are using the old toolchain to do the building then i dont the function that removes the splash screen found in the docs will work because this only support the new toolchain

Comment: Than you for quick response.  I found where the problem was, it was an authentication error. I fixed it. It was not because of "Failed to import “android” module. Could not remove android presplash".

Comment: Another help I need, How to upgrade kivy 1.9.1 to 1.9.2 in windows.

Comment: @RopjyotiBoruah it's in the documentation.